# Searching for and deleting files with a certain extension or ending with a number

Tags: command-line, find

I'd like my script to find a certain file type and delete it.

I know that `find path/to/directory/ -type f -name '*.ext' -delete` will find and delete all files with the extension.

Now I'd also like to have my script remove any file ending with a number regardless of the extension, as well as the files ending with the extension.

I tried the following commands with no success:

```
find path/to/directory/ -type f -name '*.ext' -name '*[0-9].* -delete
find path/to/directory/ -type f -name '*.ext' '*[0-9].* -delete
find path/to/directory/ -type f -name '*.ext,*[0-9].* -delete
```

None of these worked, I'm not sure what exactly I need to change or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remove the files ending with extension as well as any file ending with a number regardless of the extension

That requires conditions joined by logical OR instead of the default logical AND (parentheses are required because OR has lower precedence than AND, and they must be escaped or quoted so that the shell passes them to `find` as literals):

```
find path/to/directory/ -type f \( -name '*.ext' -o -name '*[0-9].*' \) -print
```

Change `-print` to `-delete` once you are certain that it's doing the right thing. In the GNU implementation of `find`, you may use `-or` in place of `-o` if you prefer.

Comment: thank you for the quick respond, I'm fairly new to scripting, I suppose -o means "or" but why do I need the \ in this?

Comment: @Mahmoud the parentheses must be escaped `\(` or quoted `'('` so that the shell passes them to `find` as literals

Comment: so I could write this ```\( -name '*.ext' -o -name '*[0-9].*' \)``` like this instead ```'( -name '*.ext' -o -name '*[0-9].*' )'``` correct?

Comment: @Mahmoud no, each individual `(` or `)` needs to be quoted as a separate token `'(' -name '*.ext' -o -name '*[0-9].*' ')'`